# What happens if you unpin all the tiles on Windows Phone?

Tags: pin-to-start

I wonder what it will look like? A blank screen? Or will some words be shown?

Yes I know I can just do it, but I don't want to lose my customizations and I feel like adding an interesting question here. Cheers

Comment: It goes straight to the app list. Let's find the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does go straight to the app list.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlYeePFKZ54